# BTYD package in R: error in `pnbd.plotFreqVsConditionalExpectedFrequency` and `pnbd.plotRecVsConditionalExpectedFrequency`

Tags: r, plot

I have some troubles when I try to make plots using functions `pnbd.plotFreqVsConditionalExpectedFrequency` and `pnbd.plotRecVsConditionalExpectedFrequency`.

So the first error says `Error in if (max.length%%length(x)) warning("Maximum vector length not a multiple of the length of x") : argument is not interpretable as logical`.

And the second error says `Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values`.

Could anyone help me with these errors?

[image: The screenshot of my code]

Comment: were you able to debug and fix this issue? I am facing the same error.